# PhoneGap saving sessions/cookies with external php

Tags: php, html, session, cookies, cordova

I've created a login script for my phone gap application, using php. the php is hosted on a server and referenced within the html.

However, the logged in username is saved in the session of the domain where the php files are, I need it to be in the domain of the phonegap files, or be able to check the external session at the top of each page.. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you cant have session within the app, but when logging in you can set it in the session of domain and then, when communicating with server while doing some actions (like posting comment orso) you can check the session on domain.